# Currency exchange not working on products

Tags: product, magento-1, price, currency

The default currency for my site is EUR but I want to change it to RON. I've followed the steps from Configuration->Currency Setup but I'm not exactly sure how this thing works. One of my product's initial price was 100 EUR and after the currency change it still remains at 100 RON (it should be 456 RON).

Any ideas how to make the currency exchange work?

Comment: Did you set currency rates?
See this link http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/currency-rates-update.html

Comment: I had to add both RON and EUR to the allowed currency list in order to make the values conversion. Thx

Comment: What do you want? Change base currency from EUR to RON and want automatic change product price from 100 EUR to 456 RON in backend? It doesn't work, only price with display currency on storefont can change like that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have currency rates defined in your system.

On the Admin menu, select **System > Manage Currency Rates.**

Check the rates that have been defined like 1 Euro should be 4.56 Ron. From this magento will automatically calculate price for the currency set for the stores.

For more information refer [this](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/currency-rates-update.html)